# Passando valores de um select para subselect

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join, where

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
 SELECT rp.colaborador as codigo_, t.nome, count(rp.*) as presencas, 
    ((100 * (select count(rp.*) from empresa.cad_reuniao_presencas rp 
    join empresa.cad_terceiros t on t.codigo = rp.colaborador
    join empresa.cad_reunioes r on r.codigo = rp.reuniao
    where r.data_reuniao > t.data_cadastro and t.codigo = ?
    group by rp.colaborador, t.codigo )) / (select max(codigo) from empresa.cad_reunioes rp) || '%') as porcentagem 
    FROM empresa.cad_reuniao_presencas rp 
    join empresa.cad_terceiros t on t.codigo = rp.colaborador
    join empresa.cad_reunioes r on r.codigo = rp.reuniao
    where r.data_reuniao > t.data_cadastro
    group by t.nome, rp.colaborador order by presencas desc;
```

Onde tem o `?` (ponto de interrogação) gostaria de passar o código do Terceiro para pegar corretamente a porcentagem de comparecimento nas reuniões, como poderia fazer isso? Se eu colocar um valor fixo funciona, mas ai em todas as linhas aparece somente de um Terceiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giancarlo, você pode utilizar tabelas temporárias ou join com o select, segue exemplos abaixo.

Utilizando tabela temporária.

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLE_PORCENTAGEM (
QUANTIDADE BIGINT,
CODIGOT NVARCHAR(MAX)
)



INSERT INTO #TABLE_PORCENTAGEM (QUANTIDADE, CODIGOT)
select 
    count(rp.*), 
    t.codigo 
from 
    empresa.cad_reuniao_presencas rp 
    join empresa.cad_terceiros t on t.codigo = rp.colaborador
    join empresa.cad_reunioes r on r.codigo = rp.reuniao
where
     r.data_reuniao > t.data_cadastro
group by 
    rp.colaborador, 
    t.codigo 


 SELECT
     rp.colaborador as codigo_, 
     t.nome, 
     count(rp.*) as presencas, 
     ((100 * ISNULL(tp.QUANTIDADE,0)) / (select max(codigo) from empresa.cad_reunioes rp) || '%') as porcentagem 
FROM 
    empresa.cad_reuniao_presencas rp 
    join empresa.cad_terceiros t on t.codigo = rp.colaborador
    join empresa.cad_reunioes r on r.codigo = rp.reuniao
    left join #TABLE_PORCENTAGEM tp on tp.CODIGOT = t.codigo
where 
    r.data_reuniao > t.data_cadastro
group by 
    t.nome, 
    rp.colaborador 
order by 
    presencas desc;

DROP TABLE #TABLE_PORCENTAGEM
```

Utilizando join com select

```
 SELECT
     rp.colaborador as codigo_, 
     t.nome, 
     count(rp.*) as presencas, 
     ((100 * ISNULL(tp.QUANTIDADE,0)) / (select max(codigo) from empresa.cad_reunioes rp) || '%') as porcentagem 
FROM 
    empresa.cad_reuniao_presencas rp 
    join empresa.cad_terceiros t on t.codigo = rp.colaborador
    join empresa.cad_reunioes r on r.codigo = rp.reuniao
    left join (
                select 
                count(rp.*) as QUANTIDADE, 
                t.codigo as CODIGOT 
                from 
                    empresa.cad_reuniao_presencas rp 
                    join empresa.cad_terceiros t on t.codigo = rp.colaborador
                    join empresa.cad_reunioes r on r.codigo = rp.reuniao
                where
                     r.data_reuniao > t.data_cadastro
                group by 
                    rp.colaborador, 
             ) tp on tp.CODIGOT = t.codigo
where 
    r.data_reuniao > t.data_cadastro
group by 
    t.nome, 
    rp.colaborador 
order by 
    presencas desc;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolvi com um function, mas utilizando tabelas temporárias desconhecia.

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução para o problema que encontrei para quem tiver interesse. Criei e utilizei uma function, e no lugar do     ?  (asterisco) faço a chamada dela. O problema foi a questão de performance, o select demora 144ms na primeira vez.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  empresa.getpercpresencaterceiro(codigo_terceiro integer)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

RETURN (select(count(x.codigo)) from empresa.cad_reunioes x join   empresa.cad_terceiros t on t.codigo =  codigo_terceiro where x.data_reuniao >= t.data_cadastro);

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION empresa.getpercpresencaterceiro(integer)
OWNER TO postgres;
```